# Factory-like pattern implementation

Tags: java

I have a hierarchy of types in my program and need to be able to create them dynamically at runtime. The solution I've come up with below is not the most elegant solution. Are there ways of improving it?

Specifically would it be possible to have the method `getBuilderFor(...)` not need to instantiate the type it's trying to create in order to get a builder for that type?

```
public class Main {

    public interface E {    }

    public class EImpl implements E { }

    public interface C<V> extends E {

        interface Builder<T> { T build(); }
    }

    public abstract class CImpl<T> extends EImpl implements C<T> {

        public abstract class BuilderImpl<V extends C<?>> implements Builder<V>{  }
    }

    public interface B extends C<String> { }

    public class BImpl extends CImpl<String> implements B {

        public class BuilderImpl extends CImpl<B>.BuilderImpl<B> {
            @Override public B build() { return new BImpl(); }
        }
    }

    public interface D extends C<Double> { }

    public class DImpl extends CImpl<Double> implements D {

        public class BuilderImpl extends CImpl<D>.BuilderImpl<D> {
            @Override public D build() { return new DImpl(); }
        }
    }

    public class Factory {

        public <R extends C<?>, K extends C.Builder<R>> K getBuilderFor(final Class<R> type) {

            if (BImpl.class.equals(type)) {
                // I would ideally like to just have return BImpl.BuilderImpl() here - is it possible?
                return (K) new BImpl().new BuilderImpl();
            } else if (DImpl.class.equals(type)) {
                // I would ideally like to just have return DImpl.BuilderImpl() here - is it possible?
                return (K) new DImpl().new BuilderImpl();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a map of types (`CImpl` concrete instances) that are instantiated upon `Factory` initialization? The values of the map would be instances of `BImpl`, `DImpl`, etc, and the respective keys would be the types. The function `getBuilderFor()` would just do a map lookup and on the value returned from the map, call `BuilderImpl()` and return the result.

This approach would allow to avoid the if/else block. Additionally, it would make it easier and more elegant to add more types in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `BuilderImpl` classes can't be an inner (i.e. non-static) class of the class what it build. You have to create the builder first, then the builder will create the actual class. If the builder is an inner class it's not possible.

   (To make the `BuilderImpl` classes static you need to make static some other classes too.)
2. The `V` type parameter on `C` looks unnecessary since the interface does not use it.

   ```
   public interface C<V> extends E {
       interface Builder<T> { 
           T build(); 
       }
   }
   ```